# Trigger.io project running on web nullObj is not defined

Tags: trigger.io

When I am trying to run a trigger.io project on web all.js gives an error such as "Uncaught ReferenceError: nullObj is not defined"

I belive this causes some unwanted results on rendering the pages.
Is there any planned fix for this?

Comment: You'll need to provide more details on what you're seeing in the console and your code that's causing the error. The answer is likely to be that you are trying to use a mobile-only module or method on the web. You should branch your code using the forge.is module and add logging to determine which call is causing the problem